# How do i display my array in the mergefiles method in BinaryFile into project 9 class?

Tags: java, arrays

**Can you help me figure out how to display my merge array the one in the mergefiles method which is called a in BinaryFile into my project9 class inside where the arrow is pointing? Thanks.**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Project09 extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    int ww;
    int wh;
    String command = "";

    TextFile  textFile;
    BinaryFile binaryFile;
    double product;
    int[] searchKeys;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Frame frame = new Project09();

        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setSize(1000,800);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }

    public Project09()
    {
        setTitle("Data Structures");

        // Create Menu

        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        setMenuBar(mb);

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
        mb.add(fileMenu);

        MenuItem miAbout = new MenuItem("About");
        miAbout.addActionListener(this);
        fileMenu.add(miAbout);

        MenuItem miExit = new MenuItem("Exit");
        miExit.addActionListener(this);
        fileMenu.add(miExit);

        Menu actionMenu = new Menu("One Dimensional Structures");
        mb.add(actionMenu);



        // Text File menus

        Menu textFileMenu = new Menu("Text File");
        actionMenu.add(textFileMenu);


        MenuItem miMergeTextFile = new MenuItem("Merge Text File");
        miMergeTextFile.addActionListener(this);
        textFileMenu.add(miMergeTextFile);


        Menu BinaryFileMenu = new Menu("BinaryFile");
        actionMenu.add(BinaryFileMenu);


        MenuItem miMergeBinaryFile = new MenuItem("Merge Binary File");
         miMergeBinaryFile.addActionListener(this);
        BinaryFileMenu.add( miMergeBinaryFile);





        // End program when window is closed

        WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter()
        {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent ev)
            {
                repaint();
            }

            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent ev)
            {
                repaint();
            }

        };

        ComponentListener k = new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) 
            {
                repaint();           
            }
        };

        // register listeners

        this.addWindowListener(l);
        this.addComponentListener(k);

    }

//******************************************************************************
//  called by windows manager whenever the application window performs an action
//  (select a menu item, close, resize, ....
//******************************************************************************

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ev)
        {
            // figure out which command was issued

            command = ev.getActionCommand();

            // take action accordingly
            if("About".equals(command))
            {
                repaint();
            }
            else
            if("Exit".equals(command))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }


            else
            if("Merge Binary File".equals(command))
                    {
                        binaryFile = new BinaryFile();


                        BinaryFile b = new BinaryFile();



                        try {
                             b.mergeFiles();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        repaint();

                    }

            else
            if("Merge Text File".equals(command))
                {
                    textFile = new TextFile();

                            repaint();
                        }


        }
//********************************************************
// called by repaint() to redraw the screen
//********************************************************

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {

            // Check Command issued, take action accordingly
            ww = this.getWidth();
            Font f1 = new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,16);
            Font f = new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,12);
            g.setFont(f);;


        --> if("Merge Binary File".equals(command))
            {
                int x=100;
                int y = 140;



                int[] temp =null;

                try {
                    temp = binaryFile.mergeFiles();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                dp(g,temp,x,y);

            }
            else
            if("Merge Text File".equals(command))
            {
                int x=100;
                int y = 140;



                int[] temp =null;

                try {
                    temp = textFile.mergeFiles();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                dp(g,temp,x,y);

            }




         }

        public int dp(Graphics g, int[]a, int xs, int ys)
        {

            ww = this.getWidth();
            Font f1 = new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,16);
            Font f = new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,12);


            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setFont(f1);
            g.drawString("Original File", ww/2-40, 110);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.setFont(f);

             int x=xs;
             int y =ys;

            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            {
                g.drawString(Integer.toString(a[i]), x, y);
                x = x + 35;
                if (x>(ww-100))
                {
                    x = 100;
                    y = y + 15;
                }

                }


            return y;   
        }



        }


import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class BinaryFile extends OneDStructure
{

    JFileChooser chooser;
    public Object s;


    public BinaryFile()
    {
        dataFilePath = null;
        dataFileName = null;

    }
    public BinaryFile(String fileName, int fileSize)
    {
        dataFileName = fileName;
        size = fileSize;
        array = new int[size];
    }

    public void loadFile()
    {


        dataFilePath = null;
        dataFileName = null;

        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG );
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Open Data File");

        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            dataFilePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            dataFileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        }
        try
        {
            readFileIntoArray();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.exit(0); 
        }


    }
    public void readFileIntoArray() throws IOException
    {
        if (dataFilePath != null)
        {


            DataInputStream binaryfile = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                      new FileInputStream(dataFilePath))); 

            size=binaryfile.readInt();
            array =new int [size];


              for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
              { 
                  array[i] = binaryfile.readInt();

              }


            low = this.getMinimum();
            high = this.getMaximum();
            //  end of file detected

            binaryfile.close();

        }
        else
        {
            size = 0;
        }

    }

    public void  storeFile() 
    {
        try
        {

            createOutputFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.exit(2);
        }

    }
    public void createOutputFile() throws IOException
    {
            String outFileName = this.dataFilePath+".data";
            DataOutputStream  out = new DataOutputStream (new BufferedOutputStream(
                      new FileOutputStream(outFileName)));

            out.close();

    }   



    public int[] mergeFiles() throws IOException 
    {

        BinaryFile t = new BinaryFile();
        t.loadFile();

        BinaryFile s =new BinaryFile();
        s.loadFile();



        int[] a= new int [t.getArray().length +s.getArray().length];

        for (int i =0;i<a.length;i++)

        {

            if (i<t.getArray().length )
            {
                a[i]=t.getArray()[i];


            }

            else{

                a[i]=s.getArray()[i-t.getArray().length ];
            }





        }


        FileOutputStream f =new FileOutputStream(new File("Merge.txt" ) );
        for (int q=0;q< a.length;q++)
        {
            f.write(a[q]);


        }


        return a;
    }

  }
```

**Can you help me figure out how to display my merge array the one in the mergefiles method which is called a in BinaryFile into my project9 class inside where the arrow is pointing? Thanks.**